# How to filter array based on given sequence of elements?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to build a pipe in Angular 5 that filters my data based on a given sequence of events. For example, let's say my data is:

```
["submit","click","go_back","click",....]
```

I want to filter this data that is given by up to three inputs, so if input 1's value is "click", I only get the data with all click events (easy), but also let's say my input is ["click","submit","go_back"], then I want to filter the array so only the occurrences of that sequence is there:

```
["click","submit","go_back","click","submit","go_back","click",...]
```

How can I do this using array functions? All three sequence inputs are optional, and I only need up to three. Angular dynamically filters this using a pipe component. Here is the pipe code that doesn't work:

```
transform(events: any[], event1?: string, event2?: string, event3?: string): any {
  if (!events) { return []; }

  if (event1) {
    if (event2) {
      if (event3) {
        return events.filter((event, i) => {
          // event.event is just the string name of the event
          return (event.event === event3 && events[i-1].event === event2 && events[i-2].event === event1);
        });
      } else {
        console.log("here");
        return events.filter((event, i) => {
          return event.event === event2 && events[i-1].event === event1;
        });
      }
    } else {
      return events.filter((event, i) => event.event === event1);
    }
  } else {
    return events;
  }
}
```

This and most other ways I can think of just end up showing only the first event, although some ways I've tried it will show only those first event types but that also match the sequence (so in that second array above, it would show "click" n times if the sequence exists n times).

Comment: Should there be a `return1 after the `const sub` expression?

Comment: Maybe throwing the code in a quick stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground) or [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue) plunker could help others help you more effectively

Comment: Fixed that, i was just debugging and forgot to remove it

Comment: Can you show an example of how you use it? You may be passing the arguments incorrectly. BTW you have an absurd amount of duplication that you don't need

Comment: I have three select inputs that are bound into this pipe. The values of the select options are just strings that match each event type. You can pick up to three events in the sequence (currently have all three showing at the same time). [source](https://github.com/mosherc/event-factory/tree/master/src/app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but you were only catching one of the elements in each of your matched patterns. For instance, instead of:

```
return events.filter((event, i) => {
    return event.event === event2 && events[i-1].event === event1;
});
```

You want:

```
return events.filter((event, i) => {
    return event.event === event2 && events[i-1].event === event1 ||
        events[i+1].event === event2 && event.event === event1;
});
```

I [put together a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sv7zFspuamL2m6MhM36u?p=preview) to help you out. I tried to clean the code up a little, but feel free to keep what you have and include those other matches like I showed above.

```
transform(events: Event[], ...pattern: string): Event[] {
    const matches = (event: Event, name: string) => event && event.event === name;
    const matchesPattern = (events: Event[], pattern: string[]) =>
        events.length === pattern.length && events.every((event, i) => matches(event, pattern[i]));

    switch (pattern.length) {
        case 1:
            return events.filter(event => matches(event, pattern[0]));

        case 2:
            return events.filter((event, i) =>
                matchesPattern(events.slice(i, i + 2), pattern) ||
                matchesPattern(events.slice(i - 1, i + 1), pattern));

        case 3:
            return events.filter((event, i) =>
                matchesPattern(events.slice(i, i + 3), pattern) ||
                matchesPattern(events.slice(i - 1, i + 2), pattern) ||
                matchesPattern(events.slice(i - 2, i + 1), pattern));

        default:
            return events;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured using ORs would help. I had to make a few changes though: ...pattern: string -> ...pattern: string[], filter out undefined from the array: pattern = pattern.filter(e => e), and add a case 0: return events; as well as minor TS linting stuff.